# Can we replace live for delegate on this case scenario?

Tags: jquery

This works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".items article").click(function(){
            window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
            return false;
         });
    });
```

**However**, when the user navigates to other records trough ajax on that same page, we got an irritant refresh.
(not more irritant that my ignorance about how does that occur btw).

If I change the code to use delegate:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".items article").delegate('click', function(){
            window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
            return false;
         });
    });
```

I still got the irritating refresh.

If I change it to live, I got it with no refresh.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".items article").live('click', function(){
            window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
            return false;
         });
    });
```

I've read on stackoverflow that we should use delegate instead of live, on this case however, live seems to do the job while delegate doesn't. OR, am I using it wrongly ?

**UPDATE:**
So, and using *on*, by taking the same examples as above:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('#morespecifcelement').on('click','.items article', function() { 
  window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false; 
 });
});
```

I still got the page refreshed.

Please advice,

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: `delegate` can always replace `live`. `on` can always replace `delegate`. See the documentation which explains [*how to use `delegate`*](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) and how to transform between the 3 forms in *a fair bit of detail* including examples and remarks; see the links to `on` and `live` documentation.)

Comment: your call to `delegate` is a little off. You are supposed to delegate to some container and then pass, as an argument, the selector you wish to match inside of that container. Check out the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$(document).delegate(".items article","click",function(){

}
```

Comment: that works. the page doesn't refresh. delegate isn't deprecated as live ?

Comment: @John: It is, or more strictly saying: "_As of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method._" ([source](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)). Use `.on()` instead of `.delegate()`. If you do not have `.on()`, use `.delegate()`. If you do not have `.delegate()`, use `.live()` (but preferably using fourth, undocumented argument).

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer

`.live()` can (and **should**) always be replaced with `.delegate()` (`.on()` since jQuery 1.7).

### Example

Instead of doing:

```
jQuery(selector).live(event_type, handler);
```

you can **always** do:

```
jQuery(document).delegate(selector, event_type, handler);
```

### Why replace `.live()` with `.delegate()` (or `.on()`)

You should avoid using `.live()`, because it is inefficient: it first executed `selector` (even though the element does not exist yet, so it cannot be found) and then attaches itself to `document` (which is again inefficient), unless you will use undocumented argument (which is disabled in newer versions of jQuery, as far as I know).

### Note

That does not mean you should do exactly what is listed above - you should instead pick smaller element instead of document.

As of jQuery 1.7 you should use `.on()` instead of using `.delegate()` or `.live()`.

### Edit: Same using `.on()`

This piece of code does exactly what the previously listed examples do (except in a more efficient and modern way):

```
jQuery(document).on(event_type, selector, handler);
```

But again, attaching event handler to `document` is not a good idea, as all the events happening in it will influence the site performance.

### More specific solution

The exact code that should work in your case is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(document).on('click','.items article', function(event) {
        window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
        return false;
    });
});
```

The reason it does not work in your case is probably one of these:

1. You use jQuery older than 1.7 (where `.on()` is not available).
2. The element matched by `#morespecifcelement` selector does not exist when the document is ready (it is probably introduced later).

Comment: can you please provide an example with `on`, so that we can have the three for properly comparison please ? I've tried this form: `$("p").on("click", function(){
alert( $(this).text() );
});` as in jquery manual but, I got a refresh. Against delegate that does the job.

Comment: @MEM: Done. I have added counterpart example for `.on()`. It does exactly what initial `.live()` example does, but in a more efficient way.

Comment: @MEM: Could you explain, what you are trying to achieve with `$("p").on("click", function(){ alert( $(this).text() ); });`? This binds an event handler to all the existing paragraphs (`p` tags), to the events having type of `click`. There is something else that refreshes the page.

Comment: Please don't remove your excellent reply. For the proposes here present, `on` doesn't make it (we get a page refresh) whereas delegate actually does it. Please check my question update if interested.

Comment: @MEM: I have added more specific solution. It has to work unless your jQuery is older than 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery 1.7+ you should do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.items article', function(){
        window.location=$('a', this).attr("href"); 
        return false;
     });
});
```

The best solution would probably be to fix whatever you did wrong previously to warrant the use of javascript to get the href attribute from a link and redirect to that adress, as that is normally the default action of the `<a>` element anyway ?

Comment: The point here is to make a all group of elements (ex: given div) clickable. Isn't this a good approach ?

Comment: Not really, just going with the `a` element and styling it the way you'd like it would be better than trying to make a parent div clickable and redirecting to a link in some nested `a` element etc. In my opinion that's just trying to fix some faulty HTML markup !

Comment: but that will force me to have other block elements inside an anchor and I believe that's not a good approach as well... :( Btw, if I use on as you suggest, I still get the page refreshed. If, I use delegate as John suggests, I got no refresh and it seems to work. However, without the on. :(

Comment: @MEM - What do you mean by the page not being refreshed. Your setting the location to another URL, it SHOULD refresh, if it does'nt you did something wrong ? There's no way your site is going to a different URL without some sort of refresh, unless you are using the history API and forgot to mention it. Are you sure you are not just looking for preventDefault() ?

Comment: I didn't say the page didn't got refreshed. I said it gets refreshed. And that's the issue. On a given page we have several articles. Users can navigate forward and previous on those articles using ajax pagination. If the user goes forward, and then comes back, we got the all page refresh, and we don't want that. If, however, we use delegate, problem solved. The user can get back and forward with no refresh on the browser and with the behavior on those links preserved . Why does `on` refreshes the page, while `delegate` doesn't, it's what I don't get.